# Reuse a complex Angular4, ngrx Component/Module

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have a complex component which has a big state and lots of actions and effect with functionality like virtual scrolling, undo-redo, drag-drop etc.
All this is done using ngrx and ngrx made is very easy and elegant to handle all of this.
But there are so many smart components which have store injected in them infact there are  many dump components which are dispatching actions as well.

Now the issue is that the same component/module is to be used at 2 more places, same data structure but just retrieved from a different service.

How to refactor the code so that it can be re-used at different places?

Comment: https://github.com/ngrx/store/issues/278 <-- very similar concerns expressed here, as well as some potential solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You already have an excellent seperation of concerns by creating your component as a seperate module with NGRX handling the components internal state.

All you have to do now is treat the incoming data as the components input.